# What are the best hosting for big websites/forums?

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, shared-hosting, looking-for-hosting

I bought a Deluxe hosting plan at Godaddy years ago to host my websites. Recently I decided to move one of the websites to a new host, so I have bought a new Deluxe plan for that website (which is a big forum). But since the migration, the website has been much slower than before, and I have received warnings that the resources for my account have been limited.

I realised that on these new Deluxe plans (which they call "with cPanel"), the CPU and Memory (and other) resources are limited (1 CPU core and 512 MB of memory), things never happened with the old Deluxe plans (which they call "Web classic"). (I have never had any resource problems with the other older account, even though I have used it for hosting many websites).

I'm considering cancel the order and move the website to yet another host.

Could you suggest me a hosting service (that you are using or have already used) with good amount of CPU & Memory resources at a reasonable/comparable price?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: "Web classic" probably refers to a standard "shared server" where you are sharing a powerful server and its resources with 100's (or even 1000's) of other websites. You perhaps have access to a lot of power when you need it, but resource hungry websites (perhaps yours is one!?) can rob resources from other sites and in the worst case bring down the server and all the websites on it. I'm seeing an increase in migration to "cloud platforms" where the resources are "sandboxed"... allocated to each site separately and protecting other sites from the greedy few.

Comment: Unfortunately, hosting recommendations are off-topic... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements

Comment: @w3d: thanks for the information. I'll delete the question in a few minutes.